# not getting response from share_open_graph method

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using javascript share_open_graph method to post graph story.story publishing on my wall successfully but i am not getting the post id in response. my code is
    FB.ui({
           method: 'share_open_graph',
           action_type: 'appnamespace:action',
           action_properties: JSON.stringify({
           object: "http://samples.ogp.me/--------id",
           image:"image url",
           })
         }, 
         function(response){
             console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      });

Comment: Please post what you're seeing in `response` in nicely formatted code.

Comment: FYI, this could be related to a bug that never got anywhere a while back: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/245107559024867/